# How to prevent Cordova build command from auto-generating settings.gradle

Tags: android, cordova, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, cordova-plugins

I have created a Cordova App with a custom settings.gradle as folows:

```
// GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT
include ":"
include ":CordovaLib"
include 'manager'
project(':manager').projectDir = new File('libs/ConnectManager')
```

and in build.gradle, I can refer to it as:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    debugCompile project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug")
    releaseCompile project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release")
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
    compile project(':manager')
}
```

However, when I execute command 'cordova build android', the file settings.gradle is auto-generated to a default setting which looks like:

```
// GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT
include ":"
include ":CordovaLib"
```

As a result, build always failed due to unable to locate module 'manager' that I have defined in settings.gradle.

I wonder if there is any way to prevent build command from duplicating a custom settings.gradle file.

Comment: they just move the website: Here is the link you need: [Android Shell Tool Guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/platforms/android/tools.html). If you don't find your answer, follow up here.

Comment: still, auto-generated settings.gradle was created everytime I run 'cordova build android', while it is okay when I build the same project using Android Studio.

Comment: It is unclear to me, do you need additional help on this? If need more help, please state what need. TIA

Comment: @SopheakMongkul I'm having the same issue. Have you found any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Today i faced the same problem and by spending hours i found that we can do this by change in **project.properties**

Below are the steps:

**Step-1.** Edit/Make `project.properties` in root directory and add your module as library reference after `CordovaLib`:

```
target=android-25
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2=libraryModule1
android.library.reference.3=libraryModule2
```

**Step-2.** Run `cordova build android`. This will make an entry in your `setting.gradle` file.

```
//GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT
 include ":"
 include ":CordovaLib"
 include ":libraryModule1"
 include ":libraryModule2"
```

Also your app `build.gradle` will look like this:

```
dependencies {
    ----
   // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
    releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
    debugCompile(project(path: "libraryModule1", configuration: "debug"))
    releaseCompile(project(path: "libraryModule1", configuration: "release"))
    debugCompile(project(path: "libraryModule2", configuration: "debug"))
    releaseCompile(project(path: "libraryModule2", configuration: "release"))
    ----
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

For `project(':manager').projectDir = new File('libs/ConnectManager')` this kind of setting there is no easy way i found but you can achieve in this way:

**Step-1.** /path/to/project/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js

**Step-2.** Edit fs.writeFileSync() function(Line-100)

```
  // Write the settings.gradle file.
fs.writeFileSync(path.join(this.root, 'settings.gradle'),
    '// GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT\n' +
    'include ":"\n' + settingsGradlePaths.join('')+ "'include :"+libraryModule1+" \n'+ 'include :"+libraryModule2+"');

// Update dependencies within build.gradle.
```